# send key combination via local network to other mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, imac

after a other mac or macbook is connected with a mini display port to a new generation imac you can switch between the imac and the other connected mac pressing `cmd+F2(brightness up)` using the keyboard of the imac.

i connect my macbook to my imac, switch to the macbook and connect the bluetooth keyboard and mouse of my imac to my macbook.

after that i'm not able to switch back to my imac, because the keyboard is used on my macbook. i have a second mouse connected to my imac, so i'd would be cool to switch views and control my imac with my second mouse.

is it possible to send the shortcut `cmd+F2` to my imac from my macbook? via command line or something? using apple script?

all ideas are welcome, thanks!

Comment: Could you check e.g. *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts* to see if you can change the `Cmd-F2` shortcut? Not that it's important, but I'd love to see if Apple implemented that or how that shortcut is presented to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* invoke the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 122 using command down # Cmd-F2
end tell
```

for example, by [SSH-ing](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/30/remote-login-ssh-server-mac-os-x/) into your iMac.

Execute a local script performing e.g. the SSH call on your Macbook using Butler, LaunchBar, Alfred, Quicksilver, Keyboard Maestro, or any of the other, similar tools, or simply the Services menu/Automator.

<sup>([Key code from here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-studio/2003/Dec/msg00056.html))</sup>

Comment: okay, you mean i should store this code in a `.scpt`. how do i run this script? i know how to ssh into my imac, but how tu run it?

Comment: @choise Click the link "SSH-ing" and read that web page.

Comment: seems working. but i need "brightness up", not f2... seems not the same. can't figure out the right keycode. google isnt helping me =/

Comment: @choise You mean `Fn-F2`, not `Cmd-F2`?

Comment: if i press f2(brightness) my brightness increases. and i want "cmd"+"increase brightness" . fn+f2 is real f2 on my mac

Comment: @choise Now I understand. I doubt there is a way to press one of these "special" keys programmatically. If there's no API to access this functionality programmatically, there might not be a solution.

Comment: oh :( probably i can say using apple script "change input mode" or whatever happens when i press this, after a macbook is plugged in.

Comment: @choise Haven't found an API for it -- and I don't think there is, to be honest. You also *really* should consider your question answered, or heavily edit it. It's now either about programmatic access to this functionality, or how to press a "special" key on a Mac keyboard.

Comment: @DanielBeck the link has died.

Comment: @ReydiSutandang In case it's temporary, I won't remove it for now. That said, there should be numerous guides on how to set up and use SSH with OS X online, just Google for them. It's not specific to this topic.

Comment: broken link @DanielBeck

Comment: @Mick Looks like it was permanent. Alright, just pointed it somewhere else that should apply as well.